# How do I append to a new object?

Tags: python

I have this function in python 3 that works almost as I want it to work:

```
def read_people_from_file(filename):
    """Function that reads a file and adds them as persons"""
    print("reading file")
    try:
        with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
            contents = f.readlines()
    except IOError:
       print("Error: Can not find file or read data")
       sys.exit(1)

    #Remove blank lines
    new_contents = []
    for line in contents:
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        else:
            new_contents.append(line)

    #Remove instructions from file
    del new_contents[0:3]

    #Create persons (--> Here is my problem/question! <--)
    person = 1*[None]
    person[0] = Person()
    person[0] = Person("Abraham", "m", 34, 1, 140, 0.9, 90, 0.9, 0.9)
    for line in new_contents:
        words = line.split()
        person.append(Person(words[0], words[1], words[2], words[3], words[4], words[5], words[6], words[7], words[8]))
    return person
```

In the last chunk of code, below "#Create persons", is a thing that I have not figured out how to do.
How do I create the empty list of persons and then add persons from the file?
If I remove the hard coded person named "Abraham", my code does not work.

The file is a text file with one person per row with the attributes coming after the name.

Part of the Person class looks like this:

```
class Person:
def __init__(self, name=None, gender=None, age=int(100 or 0), beauty=int(0), intelligence=int(0), humor=int(0), wealth=int(0), sexiness=int(0), education=int(0)):
    self.name = name
    self.gender = gender
    self.age = age
    self.beauty = beauty
    self.intelligence = intelligence
    self.humor = humor
    self.wealth = wealth
    self.sexiness = sexiness
    self.education = education
```

I hope that the above code is self explanatory.
I suspect that there is some more pythonian way of doing what I want.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. How about `persons = []` and `persons.append(Person())` (I added an 's' to the name). Don't complicate things.

Comment: That some cool person details you have there.. :)

Comment: What does `int(100 or 0)` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
persons = []
...
for line in new_contents:
    words = line.split()
    persons.append(Person(...))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's always:

```
persons = [Person(*line.split()) for line in new_contents]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the simplest way to do what you want:

```
def readfile():
    data = open("file path to read from","r")            #opens file in read mode
    people = []     
    for line in data:                                    #goes through each line
        people.append(Person(*line.split()))             #creates adds "Person" class to a list. The *line.split() breaks the line into a list of words and passes the elements of the list to the __init__ function of the class as different arguments.
    return people
```